# MongoDB - Fetch document with the latest Timestamp from the list of nested documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

My requirement is to fetch the last updated document from the embedded list of documents. Is there any query or aggregation I can write to get only the document that is last updated from this list of documents?

**Document Structure**

```
{
  _id: "123",
  updatedAt: ISODate("2023-03-02T14:04:37.925+00:00"),
  embedded: [
    {
      _id: "456",
      updatedAt: ISODate("2023-04-02T14:04:37.925+00:00")
    },
    {
      _id: "789",
      updatedAt: ISODate("2023-04-10T14:04:37.925+00:00")
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to fetch the document with _id: "789" as it is the last updated document in the embedded list. I want to do this for all the root documents which have embedded key.

**Expected Result**

```
{
   _id: "123",
   updatedAt: ISODate("2023-03-02T14:04:37.925+00:00"),
   embedded: [
     {
       _id: "789",
       updatedAt: ISODate("2023-04-10T14:04:37.925+00:00")
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MongoDB version is 5.2 and above, you can work with `$sortArray` to sort the document in the array and next with `$first` to get the first element.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      embedded: [
        {
          $first: {
            $sortArray: {
              input: "$embedded",
              sortBy: {
                updatedAt: -1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yPdpZzQDpc4)

Comment: I have a similar issue, where I have the same structure as above but now the embedded documents have another embedded list of documents. I want to sort of the timestamps of these nested embedded documents. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, I have created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76144679/mongodb-fetch-document-with-the-latest-timestamp-from-multiple-levels-of-neste

I hope it is clear on what I am trying to achieve, please have a look at it