# MongoDB - Fetch document with the latest Timestamp from multiple levels of nested documents

Tags: mongodb

My requirement is to fetch the last updated document from the multiple levels of embedded list of documents. Is there any query or aggregation I can write to get only the document that is last updated from this list of documents?

**Document Structure**

```
{
  _id: "123",
  updatedAt: ISODate("2023-03-02T14:04:37.925+00:00"),
  embedded: [
    {
      _id: "456",
      updatedAt: ISODate("2023-04-02T14:04:37.925+00:00"),
      nested:[
           {
             _id: "147",
             updatedAt: ISODate("2023-04-15T14:04:37.925+00:00")
           },
           {
             _id: "258",
             updatedAt: ISODate("2023-03-11T14:04:37.925+00:00")
           }
        ]
    },
    {
      _id: "789",
      updatedAt: ISODate("2023-04-10T14:04:37.925+00:00")
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to fetch the document with _id: "147" as it is the last updated document in the embedded list. I want to do this for all the root documents which have embedded key. In simple terms I want to sort on all the timestamps at any level and give out the latest updated document. I don't need to know at which level I found out the latest updated document, but the timestamp of that document. Have to keep in mind that the 1st level nested document might not have another level of embedded list of documents, Yet it needs to be compared to other documents in the list and their timestamps.

**Expected Result**

```
{
   _id: "123",
   updatedAt: ISODate("2023-03-02T14:04:37.925+00:00"),
   embedded: [
     {
        _id: "147",
        updatedAt: ISODate("2023-04-15T14:04:37.925+00:00")
     },
   ]
}
```

Comment: is the embedded 2 level

Comment: yes, maybe I will change the key, but I can have 2 level nested list of documents and all these have timestamps if the document is present

Comment: Will `"embedded"` always exist in the document?

Comment: Can `"embedded"` exist and be an empty array?  Can `"nested"` exist and be an empty array?

Comment: not necessary, but on the root level I could write a match stage to get all the documents which have embedded, then on those documents I need to figure out a way to fetch the document with the latest timestamp, **"nested"** could be present or not  inside the embedded list of documents, if it is present then that timestamp needs to be compared to all the embedded level timestamps as well to figure out if that is the latest timestamp.

embedded wont be an empty array, but nested could be present and can be an empty array

Comment: So, the document-level `"updatedAt"` is irrelevant?

Comment: yes, my requirement is to figure out when a root level document is last updated. By root level I mean I am assuming all the nested records are part of the root document and I need the latest timestamp from a document which is at any level. Also inside Expected Result embedded can also be an object instead of an array as I need just the document which has the latest timestamp not an array of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking all `"updatedAt"` dates into consideration, here's one way to find the document with the most recent date.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "updatedAt": 1,
      "newestUpdatedAt": {
        "$cond": [
          {"$eq": [{"$type": "$embedded"}, "array"]},
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$embedded",
              "initialValue": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "updatedAt": "$updatedAt"
              },
              "in": {
                "$cond": [
                  {"$eq": [{"$type": "$$this.nested"}, "array"]},
                  {
                    "$reduce": {
                      "input": "$$this.nested",
                      "initialValue": {
                        "$cond": [
                          {"$gt": ["$$this.updatedAt", "$$value.updatedAt"]},
                          {
                            "_id": "$$this._id",
                            "updatedAt": "$$this.updatedAt"
                          },
                          "$$value"
                        ]
                      },
                      "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                          {"$gt": ["$$this.updatedAt", "$$value.updatedAt"]},
                          {
                            "_id": "$$this._id",
                            "updatedAt": "$$this.updatedAt"
                          },
                          "$$value"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "$cond": [
                      {"$gt": ["$$this.updatedAt", "$$value.updatedAt"]},
                      {
                        "_id": "$$this._id",
                        "updatedAt": "$$this.updatedAt"
                      },
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "updatedAt": "$updatedAt"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"newestUpdatedAt.updatedAt": -1}},
  {"$limit": 1}
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("644f44d1820a8702096444e5"),
    "newestUpdatedAt": {
      "_id": ObjectId("644f44d1820a8702096444ea"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-05-01T22:40:11Z")
    },
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2023-02-20T10:38:53Z")
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qb0w1th7oQI).

Comment: You don't needed `$reduce`, simply use the `$max` operator on the arrays.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit How would I pickup the accompanying `"_id"`?

Comment: Then use `$sortArray` and `$first`, should have better performance

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  Could be right.  Seems like there would still be a bit of _"housekeeping"_ checking for existence and the different levels.